# nosetests import error for a module in the same directory

Tags: python, importerror, nose

I'm trying to use nosetests to run my tests in a directory structure like this:

```
project
  -src
    - __init__.py
    - file1.py
    - file2.py
  -test
    - __init__.py
    - test_file1.py
```

- `test_file1.py`  includes: `from src import file1`
- `file1.py` includes: `import file2`

When I ran nosetests in the directory of project, it raised an error:

> ImportError: No module named 'file2'

If I change `file1.py` to include: `from . import file2`, then nosetests can run without error. However, when I look at others' code, it seems unusual to add `from .` before importing a module in the same directory.

How should I make nosetests work without using `from .` in `file1.py`?

Comment: It should be `from src import file1`

Comment: Thanks for your edit. Sorry, it's my typo. I have modified it to "from src import file1"

Comment: Are you using absolute or relative imports?

Comment: It specifies how you should import your files, with an absolute path or a relative path (relative means relative to the current file's path)

Comment: I see, but how to specify that?  I have list all the import related codes in the question.

Comment: Why not use `from src import file2`.

Comment: @BarunSharma  using "from src import file2" will work as using "from . import file2", but it looks strange for me why we have to add "from ..." when we import a module in the same directory.